# Round value using selection of drop down menu / radio button

Tags: javascript, xhtml

This consists of two problems. The first problem is rounding numbers to a certain decimal point. The second problem is connecting the drop down menu to the right decimal.

First my code:

```
<style>
  span{font-style:italic;}
  span{color:green;}
</style>

<script>
    function calcul(){
            var sales = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sales").value);
            var OpExp = parseFloat(document.getElementById("OpExp").value);
            var TaxAll = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TaxAll").value);
            var Depre = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Depre").value);
            var Divid = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Divid").value);
            var TaxR = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TaxR").value);
            //GP = Gross Profit
            var GP = sales - OpExp;
            //TaxInc = Taxable Income
            var TaxInc = GP + TaxAll;
            //NetInc = Net Income
            var NetInc = TaxInc - ((TaxR / 100) * TaxInc);
            document.getElementById("NetIncome").innerHTML= 
            TaxInc - ((TaxR / 100) * TaxInc);
            //AtRE = Addition to Retained Earnings
            document.getElementById("AtRE").innerHTML = NetInc - Divid;
        }
</script>

<form action="" id="nothing">
In 2007 the British building firm Balfour Betty plc had sales of 
<input type="text" id="sales" maxlength="6" size="6"> 
million, total operating expenses of 
<input type="text" id="OpExp" maxlength="6" size="6"> 
million, a tax allowance (rebate) of 
<input type="text" id="TaxAll" maxlength="6" size="6"> 
million because of past losses, and 
<input type="text" id="Depre" maxlength="6" size="6"> 
depreciation. <strong>What is the net income of the
firm?</strong><br />
<br />
Balfour Betty plc paid out <input type="text" id="Divid" maxlength="6" size="6"> million 
in cash dividends. <strong>What is the addition to retained earnings?</strong><br />
<br />
The tax rate is <input type="text" id="TaxR"  maxlength="6" size="6"> %.<br />
<br />
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="but" onclick="calcul()" /><br />
<br />
</form>

<strong>The Net Income of Balfour Betty plc is </strong><span id="NetIncome">XXX</span>
<strong> million</strong><br />
<br />
<strong>The addition to retained earnings of Balfour Betty plc is </strong><span id="AtRE">
XXX</span><strong> million</strong>
<br />
<br />
```

The first problem: rounding numbers. The following answer: `<span id="NetIncome">` needs to be rounded dynamically. I've tried to add a new variable called `RNetInc` and add the following equation `RNetInc = NetInc.toFixed(4)`, but it only gave me two decimals, and after a refresh it doesn't even work anymore. What is the best way to round the answer to N decimals?

The second problem is one I don't know if it's possible. What I have in mind is the following:
A dropdown menu

```
<select>
    <option value"1">1 decimal</option>
    <option value"2">2 decimals</option>
    <option value"3">3 decimals</option>
</select>
```

So, what I want is that when I click `N decimal`, the answer will change to N decimal. This is a very complex situation, but one I often need.

Since I only know the (very) basics of Javascript, even using Google I cannot find the answer. Can someone get me on the right track (if it's even possible)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to fix only the final results, [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string.

HTML for `select`:

```
<select id="dec">
    <option value="1">1 decimal</option>
    <option value="2">2 decimals</option>
    <option value="3">3 decimals</option>
</select>
```

In `calcul()`:

```
var decs = +(document.getElementById('dec').value); // Add this line
document.getElementById("NetIncome").innerHTML = (TaxInc - ((TaxR / 100) * TaxInc)).toFixed(decs);
document.getElementById("AtRE").innerHTML = (NetInc - Divid).toFixed(decs);
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMgeh/3/) (updated).

**EDIT**

Looks like I've partially missunderstood your question. Please check the updated fiddle, now you can also change the amount of decimals at any time by picking a value from `select`.

Comment: The previous one was actually already good, but the edited version is even better.

It definitely works, but I've got a question:

I don't really understand this bit of code:

`var calculated = false;
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('dec').addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (calculated) calcul();});   
}`

Comment: @user2686401 The `if` prevents `calcul()` to execute before `Calculate` button is clicked at least once. There is `calculated=true` in `calcul()`. This is called flagging. If you'll create a validation system into `calcul()` you can remove flagging.